# How to connect to a SQL Server instance with C# using Visual Studio

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio

I am unable to connect to SQL Servers that have the '\' char which is used when connecting to a server instance. Any other type of server works without any issues. Any support or resource on this issue would be extremely helpful as I have exhausted my possible solutions.

Thanks!
Chris

I have tried:
-  adding/removing the '@'
-  using a double '\'
-  hard coding the server name and connecting

```
var masterConnString = $@"Server={Server}; Database={ProjectCode}; Trusted_Connection=True;";

using (var connection = new SqlConnection(masterConnString))
{                
     connection.Open();
     //do something
     connection.Close();
}
```

The following error occurs:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException   HResult=0x80131904   Message=A
>   network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing
>   a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not
>   accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL
>   Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named
>   Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)
>   Source=.Net SqlClient Data Provider

Update:

When attempting to update the SQL Server Configuration Manager the connection fails due to lack of permissions.

Comment: Are you sure the server can see/connect to the server and that the permissions that are running the app have access to the DB?  (no firewall, port, or other issues)?

Comment: So you're trying to connect to a named instance. Be sure that the Sql Server Browser service is running. Also check if the TCP/IP protocol is enabled in the Sql Configuration Manager. You might also try variations of your connection string. A good resource is www.connectionstrings.com...

Comment: Can you access the db from SSMS using whatever user is running this app?

Comment: Please show how you populate `Server` and `ProjectCode`

Comment: @JasonEades Hi yes, accessing the db from SSMS gives me no issues. Trying to do so programmatically does though.

Comment: @Brad There are no issues with access since I am able to connect to servers that do not include the '\' char.

Comment: @DStanley ProjectCode is a user entered string and Server is a String retrieved from SQL with the following line: Server = reader.GetSqlValue(0).ToString();

Comment: @PeterSchneider Hi Peter, when I attempt to use Sql Configuration Manager the connection fails due to lack of access. Do you think this is the reasoning behind the error?

Comment: This [troubleshoot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/troubleshoot-connecting-to-the-sql-server-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15) may help you.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the trusted param and add this param

"Integrated Security=SSPI"

This always works with me when the server don't have any authentication

Comment: Hi this change unfortunately resulted in the same error.